# A better way of resizing a child image while keeping its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering whether there's a better way of maintaining the image aspect ratio of the images (e.g. the rollover thumbs). It currently uses transparent images that are 3*2 big; without them, you cannot see the images. I tried to use a div that's 3*2 instead but didn't work.

Is there an alternative method of doing this? Because every time the transparent images are loaded, it put strain on the server as the images have to be linked to something. I also tried changing it to images without a source, i.e.:

```
<img src="" width=3 height=2>
```

Instead of:

```
<img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/">
```

But it didn't work. I wouldn't mind using images if they didn't link to a server. Curious to hear your thoughts!

```css
#images-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

#details-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
#main-image {
  width: 80.5%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  height: auto;
}
#test {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#main-image>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

#image-thumbs {
  width: 17.5%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  /* make it only scroll when exceeds height of main image */
  /* max-height: 400px;  make this the height of #main-image */
}

.image-thumb {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 66.6666666666666%;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.image-thumb:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.image-thumb>img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images-wrap">
  <div id="main-image" style="background-image: url('http://elephant-family.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_77217466.jpg')">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' viewBox%3D'0 0 3 2'%2F%3E" width="3" height="2" id="main-image-sizer" />
  </div>
  <div id="image-thumbs">
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      
    </div>
    <canvas onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')" width=3 height=2>
    </canvas>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      
    </div>
    <script>
      // hides overflow scroll if less than 5 thumbs
      var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('image-thumb');
      var thumbsWrap = document.getElementById('image-thumbs');
      if (thumbs.length < 5) {
        thumbsWrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      // makes '#image-thumbs' not exceed the height of '#main-image'
      var mainImgHeight = document.getElementById('main-image-sizer').style.height;
      var imageThumbsInitialHeight = document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height;
      if (imageThumbsInitialHeight > mainImgHeight) {
        document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height = mainImgHeight;
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: resizing the browser window still keeps the image aspect ratios

UPDATE: it seems that the canvas tag nearly does the trick, but leaves margin that doesn't seem to be adjustable!

UPDATE 2: it seems that the canvas tag may have solved it

UPDATE 3: code now includes both canvas and padding solutions

Comment: You could probably use a placeholder svg that would be in your html thus not needing a trip to the server

Comment: I tried that with <img src="" width=3 height=2> - or is this not coded correctly? if so, how would it be coded?

Comment: just realised I can use this instead, but it doesn't really solve the problem: <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' viewBox%3D'0 0 3 2'%2F%3E" width="3" height="2" /> - as it wouldn't work unless connected to the internet. Is there no actual solution just using html & css? using an image to resize seems very bizarre to me

Comment: if you want to keep the original image aspect ratio, you have to either set the height or the width, not both.

PD: its recomended to set hieght and width on css (html5 for img)

Comment: Why don't you just use `padding-bottom: 73.375%` on `image-thumb` and remove the transparent image

Comment: @LPZadkiel so are you saying it's better not to use a canvas? Huangism's solution works, but with the percentage of padding it's less clear immediately to the naked eye, so just wondering whether there's something clearer despite it working. I've edited my code to include the 2 solutions: canvas and padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `padding-bottom` on `image-thumb` and set it to the ratio of the image in %.

I got 73.375% from 587 / 800, for that first tiger image, I have removed all the transparent placeholders. Use 66.66666% if you just want 2/3

```css
#images-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

#details-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
#main-image {
  width: 80.5%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  height: auto;
}
#test {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#main-image>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

#image-thumbs {
  width: 17.5%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  /* make it only scroll when exceeds height of main image */
  /* max-height: 400px;  make this the height of #main-image */
}

.image-thumb {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 73.375%;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.image-thumb:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.image-thumb>img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images-wrap">
  <div id="main-image" style="background-image: url('http://elephant-family.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_77217466.jpg')">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' viewBox%3D'0 0 3 2'%2F%3E" width="3" height="2" id="main-image-sizer" />
  </div>
  <div id="image-thumbs">
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      
    </div>
    <canvas onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')" width=3 height=2>
    </canvas>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')">
      
    </div>
    <div class="image-thumb" onmouseover="$('#main-image').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')">
      
    </div>
    <script>
      // hides overflow scroll if less than 5 thumbs
      var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('image-thumb');
      var thumbsWrap = document.getElementById('image-thumbs');
      if (thumbs.length < 5) {
        thumbsWrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      // makes '#image-thumbs' not exceed the height of '#main-image'
      var mainImgHeight = document.getElementById('main-image-sizer').style.height;
      var imageThumbsInitialHeight = document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height;
      if (imageThumbsInitialHeight > mainImgHeight) {
        document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height = mainImgHeight;
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that's a good idea, although i believe it should be 66.666666% rather than 73, but it works!

Comment: The percentage is worked out with the width and the height of the image and it is exact. 66.666.. is not accurate to the tiger image, maybe it applies to the lion one, anyway you have the formula on how it works, this number will differ depending on the image

Comment: all images need to have a 3:2 aspect ratio, so 66.6% was just 2 divided by 3

Comment: Oh I see you want the custom ratio then yea 66.6666