# Keeping the aspect ratio without getting rid of excess scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the main image (elephant) to keep its 3:2 aspect ratio kept when shrinking the browser window. The problem is, if you open the demo on full screen and start shrinking the browser, there will be a point where the main image will lose its 3:2 aspect ratio, because it will try to get rid of the excess y-scroll on the image thumbs first. I want it to not try to get rid of the vertical scroll but instead keep the main image 3:2 aspect ratio.

Is it actually possible to achieve this? Note that every image has a 3:2 aspect ratio, which needs to be kept.

I'm curious to see what people think here. Thanks!

```css
#images-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
    max-width: 800px;
}
#details-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
#main-image {
  width: 80.5%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
    max-height: 400px;
}
#image-thumbs {
  width: 17.5%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 400px;
  /* make it only scroll when exceeds height of main image */
  /* max-height: 400px;  make this the height of #main-image */
}
.image-thumb {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  /* padding-bottom: 66.6666666666666%; */
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.image-thumb:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="images-wrap">
  <canvas id="main-image" style="background-image: url('http://elephant-family.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_77217466.jpg')" width="3" height="2"></canvas>
  <div id="image-thumbs">
    <canvas class="image-thumb" onmouseover="" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')" width=3 height=2></canvas>
    <canvas class="image-thumb" onmouseover="" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')" width=3 height=2></canvas>
    <canvas class="image-thumb" onmouseover="" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')" width=3 height=2></canvas>
    <canvas class="image-thumb" onmouseover="" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')" width=3 height=2></canvas>
    <canvas class="image-thumb" onmouseover="" style="background-image: url('http://streamafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/african-lion-wallpapers-hd-648x372.jpg')" width=3 height=2></canvas>
    <canvas class="image-thumb" onmouseover="" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')" width=3 height=2></canvas>
    <canvas class="image-thumb" onmouseover="" style="background-image: url('https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F09%2F174187214.jpg&w=800&q=85')" width=3 height=2></canvas>
    <script>
      // hides overflow scroll if less than 5 thumbs
      var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('image-thumb');
      var thumbsWrap = document.getElementById('image-thumbs');
      if (thumbs.length < 5) {
        thumbsWrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      // makes '#image-thumbs' not exceed the height of '#main-image'
      var mainImgHeight = document.getElementById('main-image-sizer').style.height;
      var imageThumbsInitialHeight = document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height;
      if (imageThumbsInitialHeight > mainImgHeight) {
        document.getElementById('image-thumbs').style.height = mainImgHeight;
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an `<img>` tag instead of `<canvas>`? Seems like you're re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: because they then dont keep their aspect ratio (unless you add padding of 66.6%)

Comment: Not true. Have you ever seen a [responsive image](https://jsfiddle.net/c29o5865/)?

Comment: yes but it is true in this case, because here there are multiple images inside a parent container. Change one of the small thumb image canvases to an img and you'll see what I mean

Comment: You don't need canvas to do that. **You're re-inventing the wheel**. There's plenty of image galleries with a thumbnail preview like yours that don't run on canvas.

Comment: why? you can't do it with images, but there are alternatives, like padding and divs - I already posted about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749049/a-better-way-of-resizing-a-child-image-while-keeping-its-aspect-ratio/48750160?noredirect=1#comment84502345_48750160

Comment: This image keeps it ratio as the viewport is resized, https://jsfiddle.net/c29o5865/. Is there a **specific** reason you're using `background-image`? That's why that answer suggested using padding.

Comment: yes but the example you show is a standalone image which wouldn't work in my case. I use background image because I cannot use the image tag\

Comment: Dude, that's really important information. **This whole conversation could have been avoided if you had mentioned that in your post.** A lot of people will look at your code and wonder why you're using `<canvas>` to do what you're doing, which is not common.